# adding listview footer when listview scroll reaches the end

Tags: android, listview, scroll, footer

I need to dynamically footer which can be add or remove when ever scrollview reaches the end. at some point I also need it to be visible and at other times I need it to be invisible , since I can't change  visibility is there any other way.

I am having an on scroll listener like this

```
  listViewComments.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                if (i == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                        && (listViewComments.getLastVisiblePosition() - listViewComments.getHeaderViewsCount() -
                        listViewComments.getFooterViewsCount()) >= (commentAdapter.getCount() - 1)) {
                   // removing or adding footer
                }
            }
```

when I do like this it results in flickering of the footer even if I am calling the function once, sometimes when I scroll it gets in the middle of my listview items.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16399081/726863

Comment: I would suggest you to use Recycler View or you need to write a custom Adapter for ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your footer view :

```
listViewComments.addFooterView(yourFooterView);
```

and you can remove it :

```
listViewComments.removeFooterView(yourFooterView);
```

Don't forget to inflate your footer view first :

```
View yourFooterView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourFooterXML, null);
```

Comment: yes i did that on the commented place in the code but its flickering