# How to load more items into listview scrolling to bottom

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I load about 25 items into an ArrayList and I set up the adapter as necessary. I was wondering, is there a way to load each item in the array list 4(or 5 at a time). How would I go about executing this for a regular listview? What I don't want to do is load more from a database I just want to do more operations on what I got from the query. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398921/dynamic-listview-adding-load-more-items-at-the-end-of-scroll) as reference, but I don't fully think this would apply since I need a listview, not a recycler view.

Here's some sample code of what I think I should be doing:

```
public class StartEsole extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<Details> businessList = new ArrayList<>();
    aggregateTaskBars taskBars;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.whatsLit);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        taskBars = new aggregateTaskBars();
        taskBars.execute();

        //How would I set it to only 5 items and scroll to bottom and load 5 more
        listview.scrollToBottom( add 5 more items from businesslist and populate them into listview)

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        Log.i("AppInfo", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
                        lookForWhatsLit();
                    }
                }

        );
    }

    public class aggregateTaskBars extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Populate items into Arraylist businessList that contains details of some kind
            //should produce 20
            return null

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            listview.setAdapter(vDetailAdapter);
            vDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            valueType.setEnabled(true);
        }



}
```

Comment: " I need a recycler view, not a listview" -- But you have a ListView in this code

Comment: Woops, I'll fix that.

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: try this one<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview>