# Endless scrolling in not working in below marshmallow version

Tags: android

[image: error Image]I implemented one fragment class where data is fetching in volley response and I also implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener. Data will come at scrolling time and it's working properly on marshmallow version but not working on below version i.e Kitkat, Lollipop. When I am trying to run on below version it gives an error which is max version to run this app is 23. Please help me to solve this type of error thank you in advance.

Below is my Fragment1 class.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener{
private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private int requestCount = 1;
public Fragment1() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    getData();
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(Fragment1.this);
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    return view;
}
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("response",response.toString());
                    parseData(response);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

private void getData() {
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    requestCount++;
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Log.e("array",array.toString().trim());
        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setMglId(json.getString(Config.TAG_MGLID));
            superHero.setAgeHeight(json.getString(Config.TAG_AGEHEIGHT));
            superHero.setCommunity(json.getString(Config.TAG_COMMUNITY));
            superHero.setOccupation(json.getString(Config.TAG_OCCUPATION));
            superHero.setIncome(json.getString(Config.TAG_INCOME));
            superHero.setShortlist(json.getString(Config.TAG_SHORTLIST));
            superHero.setExpress_Intrest(json.getString(Config.TAG_EXPRESSINTREST));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        getData();
      }
    }
  }
```

And below is my gradle class

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.news.user.feedexample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}

   dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
 }
```

Comment: Hi 
can you share you app gradle file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are facing error as 'max version to run this app is 23'. 
Please check your app gradle file.
In that check you  **'minSdkVersion'**.
Make sure it is not 23.
it should be the minimum version which you wanted to support your app.

updated answer:- 
RecyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener just need api 23 and that will not run in other versions.So please try using addOnScrollListener

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int 
      newState) {
               super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

               //onScrollStateChanged will be fire every time you scroll
              if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                  getData();
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is an error on RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener and now the error is Class requires API level 23 (Current min is 19)

Comment: can you post the log

Comment: error is not coming on log and when I am running this app unfortunately app has stopped. Please check my updated code where I put gradle class

Comment: try to use addOnScrollListener

Comment: where to add this

Comment: you have added listener recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(Fragment1.this);
instead of that use this.
the code which you write in onScrollChange method.
write that in onScrollStateChanged methos.Please check updated ans.

Comment: Okey let me check