# Modern way of doing automatic "load more" in Android ListView/RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I implemented https://stackoverflow.com/a/24882417 but this question is very old. My list, when the items load, gets shifted to the top, and I have to scroll all the way to the bottom again.

I think there's a better way of doing lists that automatially update when you reach the end, so I'm asking it in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Jetpack Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) is the current recommendation here.

You should use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) instead of a `ListView`, and then you can create an adapter that subclasses [`PagedListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedListAdapter).  From there, you can created [`PagedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList) instances from your data source, and submit them to your adapter via [`submitList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedListAdapter#submitList(androidx.paging.PagedList%3CT%3E)).  You can find more information and [a detailed walkthrough](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ui) in the documentation for the Paging library.